# Trouble with proof of completeness

Tags: functional-analysis

I am getting confused trying to prove that the space of continuous bounded functions on a locally compact Hausdorff topological space is complete for the sup norm $||.||_\infty$.

For $f_n$ a Cauchy sequence in that space, we find a pointwise limit $f$ by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$. The part I have trouble with is to show $||f_n-f||_\infty\rightarrow 0$.

What I have:
$$\exists N\quad \forall n,m\geq N\quad ||f_n-f_m||_\infty\leq \epsilon/2$$
$$\forall x\quad \exists N_x\quad \forall n\geq N_x\quad |f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \epsilon/2$$

Then I'd like to use the triangle inequality somehow. I would like to find a $M$ such that for all $n\geq M$:
$$||f_n-f||_\infty\leq ||f_n-f_N||_\infty+||f_N-f||_\infty\leq \epsilon/2+\epsilon/2$$

But something is wrong here, I can't figure out how to deal with $||f_N-f||_\infty$ without somehow using the result I want to prove. What is the right method?

Comment: [This is true for any topological space as domain. No need for local compactness.] Just note that $\|g\|_\infty\leq \epsilon/2$ iff $|g(x)|\leq \epsilon/2$ for every $x$. Then you can switch the $\forall m\geq N$ and the $\forall x$. This will turn $f_m$ into $f$.

Comment: If $|f_N(x)-f_m(x)|\le\varepsilon$ for all $m>N$ then $|f_N(x)-f(x)|\ldots$

Comment: @julien: what is $g$? Do you mean switching $\forall$ and $\exists$? Is that allowed?

Comment: @Carsten: yes but the $N$ depends on $x$...

Comment: Nope. It's the $N$ from the Cauchy condition which referred to the sup norm.

Comment: $g$ was meant to be any function... Here $f_n-f_m$ and then $f_n-f$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_\epsilon$ such that
$$
m,n\ge N_\epsilon\implies |f_m(x)-f_n(x)|\le\epsilon\quad\forall x.\tag{*}
$$
You also know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$. Let $n\to\infty$ in inequality (*) to get
$$
m\ge N_\epsilon\implies |f_m(x)-f(x)|\le\epsilon\quad\forall x
$$
that is, $\|f_m-f\|_\infty\le\epsilon$.

Comment: Doesn't your $N_\epsilon$, and therefore your $m$, depend on $x$? In which case you can't just take the sup...I'm sorry I am confused by this.

Comment: No, because conference is uniform (convergence in the $\sup$-norm is equivalent to uniform convergence.(

Comment: ok I see where I was wrong, thx for that.